# How to create by default two columns for every features (One Hot Encoding)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding, feature-engineering

My feature engineering runs for different documents. For some documents some features do not exist and followingly the sublist consists only of the same values such as the third sublist `[0,0,0,0,0]`. One hot encoding of this sublist leads to only one column, while the feature lists of other documents are transformed to two columns. Is there any possibility to tell ohe also to create two columns if it consits only of one and the same value and insert the column in the right spot? The main problem is that my feature dataframe of different documents consists in the end of a different number of columns, which make them not comparable.

```
import pandas as pd 
feature = [[0,0,1,0,0], [1,1,1,0,1], [0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,1,1,1], [1,1,0,1,1], [1,0,1,1,1], [0,1,0,0,0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(feature[0])
df_features_final  = pd.get_dummies(df[0])

for feature in feature[1:]:
    df = pd.DataFrame(feature)
    df_enc = pd.get_dummies(df[0])
    print(df_enc)
    df_features_final = pd.concat([df_features_final, df_enc], axis = 1, join ='inner')


print(df_features_final)
```

The result is the following dataframe. As you can see in the changing columntitles, after column 5 does not follow a 1:

```
   0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1
0  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0
1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1
2  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0
3  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0
4  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't notice the functionality you want in pandas atleast. But, in TensorFlow, we do have

```
tf.one_hot(
    indices, depth, on_value=None, off_value=None, axis=None, dtype=None, name=None
)
```

Set depth to 2.

Comment: Ok, here's a workaround in pandas. Check if you have an array like that having only 1 unique value add a dummy value in the end. Run the dummies function. Then, remove the last row from the output.

Comment: I tried solving it with tf. For my input, the ```tf.one_hot``` shows this error:```tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Could not find valid device for node.``` Have you ever seen it?

Comment: which tensorflow u have. did u try the workaround i think it will be better if confine the code in one library.

Comment: tf is 2.1.0. I consider the tf solution as cleaner, would prefer to use it if it would work. Been stuck with this node issue for a while

Comment: can you try casting your array to np.float32.